# How to render from Eevee in Blender 2.8?

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I have the Blender 2.8 version from the 21st Sep 2018
I was looking forward to render a test sequence but cannot find a render button anywhere?
Does anyone know where to find it?

Comment: You can press CTRL + F12 for that.

Answer (score 10):

While the pre-release builds of 2.80 were setup with Alt-F12 as the render shortcut, the final 2.80 release returned to using <kbd>F12</kbd> to render an image and <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> to render an animation.

You can find each render option in the render menu at the top left of blenders window.

[image: 2.80 render menu]

The render buttons previously found with the render settings are no longer there in 2.80, although it is possible to replace them with an addon.

Answer (score 7):

In case anybody who comes here is annoyed by the change I have a tiny addon that adds the Render and Animation button back in.

[Blender2.8-RenderButton](https://github.com/Mitsuma/Blender2.8-RenderButton)