# Render button missing in Blender 2.8

Tags: rendering, interface, eevee-render-engine

So either Google doesn't have the answer, or I didn't know what to search for. But I don't see the render button on the right side of the screen. Every tutorial I see says that I'll find it there, but I don't see it.

This is what I'm seeing

[image: Screen]

Comment: You should precise that you're in 2.8. I don't know where is the Render button in the Properties panel but you can go in the top horizontal menu bar > Render

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about issues with unfinished experimental development software

Comment: I think this is a deliberate change, not an issue

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119377/how-to-render-from-eevee-in-blender-2-8

Answer (score 18):

In Blender 2.80 the render buttons are in the main window header, next to *File* and *Edit*.

[image]

Comment: When I am in render workspace, hitting CTRL+F12 launches a new window that duplicates the render workspace. How can I prevent that and have the render go just in the render workspace?

Comment: It seems Blender adopted a more logical menu structure and I'm not used to it.